# how to create a backbone view's event handler to each individual bootstrap panel collapse?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, events, backbone.js

I want to implement and event handler to change the glyphicon of a bootstrap collapse panel from closed (`glyphicon-chevron-right`) to open (`glyphicon-chevron-down`). I am implementing this in a Backbone view, and I can't figure out what is the best way to do so. I tried two different options:

(a) in the code shown below I have been trying to create a backbone event response to `hidden.bs.collapse` and `show.bs.collapse` bootstrap events, but I need to identify what exact panel is responsable for them, to add/remove the corresponding glyphicon (I don't know how to do that).

(b) another option would be to directly assign a jquery handler to each of the panels on the view `initialize()` function, similar to what is done here http://www.bootply.com/73101, but I have problems trying to figure out how to refer to the dom elements using `el`.

Any ideas? I'd appreciate your help.

#### form.html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="panel-group" >
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down "></span> Header 1
    </a>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
    Content 1
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right "></span> Header2          
       </a>
    </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
     <div class="panel-body">
    Content 2
     </div>
    </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### view

```
var formView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  className: 'form',
  template: _.template(Tmpl),

  events: {
   'hidden.bs.collapse': 'set_hidden_glyph',
   'show.bs.collapse': 'set_show_glyph',
  },

  render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this;
  },

  set_hidden_glyph: function(e){
    ... do something here...
  },

  set_show_glyph: function(){
    ... do something here...
  }

});
return formView;
```

Comment: Are the panels views in their own right? I'm not sure what the form view is actually generating, is it the markup you're showing without the wrappers?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/posizewu/1/edit I created a bin with your code. And I see the events are getting fired. What you want to do with this?? If you want all bootstrap css and glyphs to be shown add in the bin and let us know what exactly you want.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/posizewu/1/watch I have edited the bin. I have made some changes to the code to play with the arrow icon. Take a look.

Comment: @jebin Thanks very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. Clearly I don't have a good understanding of how to use jquery. Would you help explaining what `$(this.el)` and `.prev()` are exactly doing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  className: 'form',
  template: _.template($("#form").html()),

  events: {
   'hidden.bs.collapse': 'set_hidden_glyph',
   'show.bs.collapse': 'set_show_glyph'
  },

  render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template());
    return this;
  },

  set_hidden_glyph: function(e){
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
    $(e.target).prev().find("span").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-down").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-right");

  },

  set_show_glyph: function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    $(e.target).prev().find("span").removeClass("glyphicon-chevron-right").addClass("glyphicon-chevron-down");
  }

});
```

this.el is the container of the backbone view. It is a javascript selector which can be passed to the view while we instantiate, or we can create it using tagName prop in view. ALl the events registered in a view are delegated to this.el only.

prev() is a [jquery api](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) which can be used to select the precedent sibling element of the current selector.